# Loopback MongoDB - deployment

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I know this might start flame wars over which solution is better and it doesn't actually have a correct answer... but since I don't know where to look

what are currently best solutions to deploy your API to? (loopback v3 and mongoDB)...

fiddling with the AWS idea... anything else?

Comment: I'm not sure this question can have a definitive answer, and if there is an answer, it will be very use case specific and opinionated. "Best" is defined very differently from person to person, from app to app, etc. You mention AWS, what are you comparing it against? What is your criteria for being "best"?

Comment: that's the problem.... I don't know what's out there....  let's say I would like something cheap and reliable, that can easily be scalable and is easily maintainable (easy to continuously deploy)

Comment: @DS_web_developer i think digitalocean is good fast and cheaper as compare to aws next opinion is godaday is more cheaper than digital as well as aws but there is perfomance issue as compare to digital

Comment: Depends on your needs, basically: CI/CD, scalability, performance, uptime and budget. For example, Heroku provides a very straightforward CI/CD but can be expensive to scale. AWS or GCP are the most robust solutions which will fill your needs, but it depends on your budget then. Digital ocean is a good approach for personal projects though.

Comment: OK, we are getting somewhere... now I know more options... Thanks bipin and Rodrigo Mata. So for serious app, that will scale, AWS/GCP? anything else?